# Record uniqueness when using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer?

Tags: swift, cocoa, icloud, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have successfully migrated my app to use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` in order to have its data synchronised using CloudKit.

However, I am wondering how I should deal with uniqueness of certain entities. For example, assume a `User` entity that has the property `emailAddress` that needs to be unique. Now consider the case two devices create `User` instances with the same email address. In my current implementation nothing enforces uniqueness so I end up with having the 2 instances being available at both devices as soon as they get the change to synchronise.

Currently whenever I fetch entities assuming they are unique, I check if they really are and if not, merge them, including assigning relations of one of the instances to the other instance. After merging, I remove the "empty" instance. While this seems to work fine, I also can assume cases where this might go wrong: when two devices merge at the same time and end up removing different instances causing all of them to be removed.

How should I deal with cases like this?

PS. I have been searching for similar questions and found some similar questions but they all relate to explicitly using `CKRecord`. Since I am using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`, which encapsulates and simplifies CloudKit implementations, I am not working with those kind of "low level" classes.

Comment: I have the same issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527786/how-can-i-get-only-one-record-in-coredatacloudkit-environment

Answer (score 0):

`NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` uses only the user's private database zone. You'll have to have a public database zone and fetch the user records with given email. However this can be critical if you plan to enroll your app in the EU. Their strict GDPR rules won't allow to make emails publicly available.

You'll most likey end up having your own database and backend logic with your requirements.