# How can I get only unique record in coredata+cloudkit(NSPersistentCloudKitContainer) environment?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

For example, I have a entity named User in public database of Cloukit. Every new user using the App will record his identity in it, and only one record.

But in coredata+cloudkit environment, there is a user, two apple devices, two this Apps, one cloud.  Firstly, the user use this App on the phone A, check existence of User in local coredata when startup, not exist, so create a User record. It's ok. Days later, the user do the same on the second Phone B, record not exist in local(not sync from cloudkit), create another user record of the same user.

After a while, there are two records of the same user in both phone A and phone B, even in cloukit. how to avoid this?

The configuration/preferences is the same, I just want to keep my only one configuration for my App on all phones by syncing with private database of cloudkit. But for the same reason, There will be al least two.

So how can I get only one record in coredata+cloudkit environment?

Comment: We can't use unique constraints with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit

Comment: You don't say HOW you are storing the User record. Are you using CKUserIdentity or even CKUserIdentity.userRecordID?

Comment: yes, I use discoverUserIdentity to get user id.

Comment: Posting some code. is not only usual on SO, but goes a long way to answering a whole heap of questions, rather than a 'text conversation'.

Comment: It's just thought about sync between coredata and cloudkit, just an idea, no code related.